# initiating file upload within an ajax form WITHOUT submitting the entire form

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form with several fields. One of these fields requires an upload of documentation (.doc, .docx, .pdf) files. The form is an AJAX form, set up so that whenever a user leaves (blur) a field, the field content is AJAXed through to some php where it'll get saved to a MySQL database. The form for the most part works (I'm new to AJAX and really not good with JS at all) but I cannot seem to get the file upload section to work how I would like. At the moment I am hammering around with this:

The (immediately relevant) html:

```
   <td class="center" colspan="3">
    <input type="file" name="myfile"> <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    <div class="uploadProgress" style="border: 1px dotted green;">
     <div class="bar"></div>
     <div class="percent">0%</div>
     <div id="status"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="fileList"></div>
   </td>
```

The JS that is inside a .js file:

```
// AJAX file uploader
(function() {
    var bar = $('.bar');
    var percent = $('.percent');
    var status = $('#status');

    $('#uploadFile').ajaxForm({
        beforeSend: function() {
            status.empty();
            var percentVal = '0%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },

        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },

        success: function() {
            var percentVal = '100%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },

        complete: function(xhr) {
            status.html(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
})();
```

I am using jQuery and jquery.form.js

At the moment I am only trying to get this section of the form to talk to the php file, but it seems to want to html5 validate other fields marked as being "required" instead of just ignoring them and uploading the chosen file. How do I get it to do this? I don't want the entire form to be submitted each time someone clicks the upload button, I only want the single file taken care of.

Once I can get it to the php file I can deal with it easily enough, and hopefully work out how to return an output for the resulting list from there. So just getting it there to begin with is the problem.

Link to a fiddle of the page I'm trying to get the file upload function to work in. This shows what is present to begin with. http://jsfiddle.net/k3dj214k/2/

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you want only the input file to be submitted than you shouldn't submit the whole form(`uploadFile` is the whole form, right?) or you just want to pass the validation of the other fields?

Comment: @BardhLohaj #uploadFile is not the whole form, that value was originally (in the demo) 'form', which was the whole form in the demo. However I tried changing it and assigning #uploadFile to the file selector and then the upload button but neither made a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ajaxForm` prepares a form to be submitted which means that you cannot submit only a single element of the form in this way.

On the other hand, you cannot implement `ajaxForm` in a way that it bypasses the html5 validation of the other elements in case of file upload.

So:

- You could use different libraries which would allow to only upload a file from an html file input such as [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).
  Here is an [example](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin) of how you can implement only a file upload without having a form.
- You could remove the file upload element from the form and put it into another separate form so the file upload form doesn't interfere with the other form.

Comment: I had considered breaking the form and handling the file upload in a separate form. But this would be untidy, given that this is occurring fairly well in the middle of the initial form. Using a different method/library sounds like a good idea. Are you able to suggest how to accomplish this?

Comment: I added a link to an example of jQuery File Upload. Does that help you going?

Comment: Ok that is particularly cool. Except... same problem. I've spent hours trying to incorporate the Basic Plus UI version into my page and it looks nice! But when I try to upload a file, the form reports exactly the same problem. Situation looks nicer though, but problem persists.

Comment: You shouldn't submit the form when a file is uploaded. Are you still doing that or which form is reporting the same problem?

Comment: I'm working through it now, will post a result soon. I am now using the breaking form and inserting a new form specifically for the file, idea.

Comment: Ok I've discovered that it will not work correctly on screen due to the requirement of loading bootstrap.min.css (Bootstrap v2.3.2) for a key function in the form display. If I take bootstrap.min.css out, it works and you can SEE it working. If bootstrap.min.css is in the mix, it works but you cannot see. It gives a lot of blank space. Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Please check updated question, have included a jsfiddle link to the page I'm wanting to get this working in, so it can be seen overall.

Comment: I updated a bit your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k3dj214k/3/) but there are still a lot of issues in it. Load all the libraries as external resources and try to get the form in a working state than we could work on the file upload issue.

Comment: Thanks Bardh, however I've given up on trying to make this work as it's taken far too much valuable time. I've decided to take your earlier advice:

You could remove the file upload element from the form and put it into another separate form so the file upload form doesn't interfere with the other form.

And now resorted to using the jquery file upload you suggested as an iframe solution so that there are no JS/CSS conflicts. It's not the perfect solution but it is functional. Thank you.