# unexpected script/css conflict, how to resolve?

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I've asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526841/initiating-file-upload-within-an-ajax-form-without-submitting-the-entire-form/) earlier on which has been technically answered by Bardh Lohaj but unfortunately the answer itself presents a further problem. [The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526841/initiating-file-upload-within-an-ajax-form-without-submitting-the-entire-form/) is about a cool way to ajax upload files in a multi field form. The solution would work perfectly except that because the form is using bootstrap.min.css in order to display form sections in JS triggered tabs - meaning the form is nicely broken up into manageable parts while remaining all as one page, means the nice solution offered by Bardh does not function correctly. What is the best way forward to resolve the css/js conflict in order to get both functions to operate fully? I've never had this sort of problem before.

As requested, here is a fiddle of the page, I cannot get the +1 feature seated in Section 3, to work on the fiddle as it does on the real page. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k3dj214k/2/

I want to [get this](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/jquery-ui.html) working in the file upload section (Section 3) of the page on the above fiddle. I've tried several times but always with the same failure - the bootstrap.min.css that is required for the tab function, breaks the file upload function. Advice on how to get them both working together is appreciated.

```
There is too much code to paste in here, please review jsfiddle link above
```

Comment: Try to include code you've tried so far to help us. Highlight what is giving you an error. If there is much code, try to "copy" the site to a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I was afraid someone would say that. There is buckets of code... ok I'll try to arrange it in a fiddle.

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate. If you have additional requirements that make the proposed solution unusable, then you should modify your original question.

Comment: @CBroe It is not a duplicate at all, this is a second step - new question - as result of suggested answer to previous question. Not duplicate.

Comment: Is it your website http://agmardt.org.nz/ ? I see your jsfiddle and there are a lot of mistakes, but now I understand what is your idea.

Comment: It's not agmardt.org.nz but it is an additional subdomain site for that group, that has not been released yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted and used solution is not one I'm hugely proud of but it **IS** functional. Separate the upload form function from the main form so they are two separate pieces of html/php. Break the primary form part way through (close the form) and enter the file upload form as an iframe. After this, re-open the original form.

Not a wonderfully technical solution, but is does work with minimal issues/problems.